# How to add an array twice by two TRUE conditions?

Tags: python, numpy, if-statement, shift

this is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.interpolation import shift

B = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

F = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

M = np.array([[1, 2, 1, 2, 1],
          [1, 2, 1, 2, 1],
          [1, 2, 1, 2, 0],
          [1, 2, 1, 2, 1],
          [1, 2, 1, 2, 1]])

if F[2, 4] == 1:
    B = np.add(M, B)

if F[1, 4] == 1:
    M_shift = shift(M, (-1, 0), cval=0)
    B = np.add(M_shift, B)

print(B)
```

I want to add M to B if the condition for F is true. In this example both if-conditions are true and i thought that my code will add two times M to B. But apparently it's not working? What is wrong?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT for arra:

My desired output is in this case, my code snippet should add the matrix with B and also the shifted version of M. Because both conditions are True. But as u said the first assignment is overwritten. How can I prevent the overwriting for this case?

The output, after the assignment should look like this:

```
    B = np.array([[2, 4, 2, 4, 2],
                  [2, 4, 2, 4, 1],
                  [2, 4, 2, 4, 1],
                  [2, 4, 2, 4, 2],
                  [1, 2, 1, 2, 1]])
```

I guess a good way is to use a for-loop because i want to check all array entries in Matrix F, if there's a 1. But i reckon that if i use the  np.add function I'll overwrite it again

Comment: Viktor's answer seems fine -- *i.e.* the first assignment is overwritten -- but can you edit your question to be more clear?   Can you also include your desired output? When I read "I want to add M to B if the condition for F is true" the two possibilities that strike depending on the format of `F` are `B += F*M` in the case that "condition" refers to the cell values in `F` and `B += M if condition(F) else np.zeros(B.shape)` if the condition relates to some function on `F`; clearly you mean neither.

Comment: i edited the question for you arra. Is it now more clear for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overwrite B in the second if, so any previous value will be erased. Not sure what you are trying to achieve in your code, but don't you want something like:

```
B = np.add(M_shift, B)
```

or

```
intermediateVal = np.add(M_shift, F)
B = np.add(B, intermediateVal)
```

Comment: Well, thanks for the reminder! np.add(M_shift, B) solved the problem. And now its working that if the two conditions are true, the code will add it both to the matrix B